# I'm reading a differential equations textbook and a step in solving linear equation with constant coefficients has me confused.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here is the direct excerpt from the book with the step confusing me:

> $$y'=a\left(y+\frac{b}{a}\right) \implies \left(y +
>  \frac{b}{a}\right)'=a\left(y+ \frac{b}{a}\right)$$

Why is this step true?

Comment: This question will be closed if you don't explain what confuses you and type out the question without a link. But all the author is doing is adding a constant ($b/a$), which does not change the derivative.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{b}{a}$ is a constant; hence its derivative is 0.

Therefore $\left( y + \frac{b}{a} \right)' = y' + 0 = y'$ (remember that the derivative distributes over sums).

Answer (score 2):

Or put another way (in addition to William), a substitution 
$$
u=y+\frac ba
$$
is performed, so that $u'=au$. One could also substitute $v=ay+b$ to the same effect, $v'=ay'=av$.